# Gaming Rig that can Handle VR (and Roblox VR)

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, gaming, vr-headset

I’m helping my nephew put together a system that will allow him to play Roblox VR on his Oculous Quest 2 headset. With my knowledge and research, the things I’ve been keeping in the back of my head as minimum must-haves are Ryzen 5 3600 processor, 16 gb RAM and an NVIDIA GTX 1660 GPU. Not too sure about motherboards…. how much of a part do they play? And I’m not really sure about the cooling needs.

https://skytechgaming.com/product/chronos-mini-amd-ryzen-5-3600-nvidia-geforce-gtx-6gb-500gb-ssd-16gb-ram/
I found this prebuilt system that looks pretty good to me. Anyone have any reasons against it or better suggestions for roughly the same $$? Is upgrading to the B450M Pro4 mobo advised in order to get longer life out of it (with a video card upgrade down the road) or are we looking at a whole new rig to jump to the next performance level from here, should he get really into it?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A higher end motherboard doesnt matter much in performance with that cpu, its mostly the the gpu and cpu that matters. That prebuilt pc looks pretty good, especially with the high gpu prices right now. If the prices are going down, maybe you can get an rtx 3060 and a better psu, but that pc looks pretty good.